# Do I need an Internet connection when using SKStoreReviewController?

Tags: ios, swift, skstorereviewcontroller

When I'm asking the user to rate my app should I make sure there is an Internet connection? What happens if there is no Internet? Apple documentation does not clarify this. Should I assume that it is store locally and when there is a connection it will be updated?

```
  if let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first(where: { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }) as? UIWindowScene {
   SKStoreReviewController.requestReview(in: scene)
  }
```

Comment: What happened when you experimented?

Comment: Is there anyway to experiment besides using live code?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to check for internet connectivity first. Apple will take care of these scenarios and it that's a authentic review it will be added to your app on the store otherwise it will be rejected away, So the whole internet logic is hidden and taken care by the OS itself.